# Which versions of google-cloud-pubsub and mysql-connector-python are compatible?

Tags: mysql-python, google-cloud-pubsub, python-3.10, protobuf-c

I'm setting up a project that will utilize both a MySQL DB and Google PubSub and it will be hosted in GCP. I'm working on the dependencies and I ran into an error when installing both packages:

- mysql-connector-python==8.0.32
- google-cloud-pubsub==2.17.1
  and they are not compatible.

The main issue is `protobuf` since it has conflicting dependencies:

The conflict is caused by:
`The user requested protobuf==4.23.3 google-api-core 2.11.1 depends on protobuf!=3.20.0, !=3.20.1, !=4.21.0, !=4.21.1, !=4.21.2, !=4.21.3, !=4.21.4, !=4.21.5, <5.0.0.dev0 and >=3.19.5 google-cloud-pubsub 2.17.1 depends on protobuf!=3.20.0, !=3.20.1, !=4.21.0, !=4.21.1, !=4.21.2, !=4.21.3, !=4.21.4, !=4.21.5, <5.0.0dev and >=3.19.5 googleapis-common-protos 1.59.1 depends on protobuf!=3.20.0, !=3.20.1, !=4.21.1, !=4.21.2, !=4.21.3, !=4.21.4, !=4.21.5, <5.0.0.dev0 and >=3.19.5 grpc-google-iam-v1 0.12.6 depends on protobuf!=3.20.0, !=3.20.1, !=4.21.1, !=4.21.2, !=4.21.3, !=4.21.4, !=4.21.5, <5.0.0dev and >=3.19.5 grpcio-status 1.54.2 depends on protobuf>=4.21.6 mysql-connector-python 8.0.32 depends on protobuf<=3.20.3 and >=3.11.0`

I tried using multiple versions of `google-cloud-pubsub`. But I cannot find the dependencies of this package for its older versions specifically.

Other than try-and-error is there an overview of its dependencies or has anyone set up a project with both packages and share the versions they used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across this question: I used `SQLAlchemy==2.0.16`  and rewrote the MySQL operations. That solved the issue.